# React Native Dynamic Styling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating s crypto app where I want to change background color to red when the price went down and green when Price went up and then after 2 seconds change the background back to normal using setTimeout.

I tried two different methods to at-least change the backgroundColor but on both the occasion i got the following error

> You attempted to set the key backgroundColor with the value  #ffe5e5
>   on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.

I asked the [separate question for the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820659/react-native-you-attempted-to-set-the-key-on-an-object-that-is-meant-to-be-immu/51820969#51820969) but for some reason, the response I received was not convincing.

Afterwords, i tried a different approach (the one which does not allow the use of StyleSheet) but I still got the same error.

I am putting my new code here (you can refer to my previous code from the question)

First I declared an object in a global scope like this

```
var upperRow = {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 5, 
    backgroundColor: "white"
} 


class  CoinCard extends Component {
```

then I tried to change background color like this

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if (this.props.coinPrice != nextProps.coinPrice ) {
       if (this.props.coinPrice > nextProps.coinPrice) {

           upperRow["backgroundColor"] = "#ffe5e5";
 }
}
```

followed by assigning the styles like this

```
return (

    <View style={container}>

            <View style={upperRow}>
```

**[Question:]** How can I change the styling dynamically?

Comment: Just wondering, is there any reason it's a variable outside of `CoinCard`?

Comment: @Dan No specific reason, probably a bad coding practise in an attempt to make things work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to keep in state whether or not your coin has decreased recently.
Imagine a state of this shape:

```
state = {
  hasIncreased: boolean,
  hasDecreased: boolean,
}
```

Now you can change this state in the `componentWillReceiveProps` (this is now deprecated though, so if you are on 16.3 or higher, maybe look in phasing its use out) like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.coinPrice < this.props.coinPrice)
    this.setState({hasDecreased: true, hasIncreased: false})

  if (nextProps.coinPrice > this.props.coinPrice)
    this.setState({hasIncreased: true, hasDecreased: false})
}
```

Now that you have this state, you can add some styles conditionally:

```
render() {
  const {hasIncreased, hasDecreased} = this.state
  return (
    <View style={[ //styles can be an array!
      upperRow, 
      hasIncreased && {backgroundColor: 'green'},
      hasDecreased && {backgroundColor: 'red'},
    ]}/>
  )
}
```

Now all that's left is to reset state after 2 seconds. To me, it seems best to use the `componentDidUpdate`-lifecycle for that

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // only queue the reset if it's actually necessary, not on random updates
  if (prevProps.coinPrice !== this.props.coinPrice) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    // we need to be able to reset the timeout
    this.timeout = setTimeout(
      () => this.setState({hasDecreased: false, hasIncreased: false}),
      2000,
    )
  }
}
```

You should try avoiding just changing the styles like that in a mutable manner. The whole point is that your state should reflect what you display.

Comment: excellent  answer, just one thing I am unable to get what you mean here `upperRow, 
      hasIncreased && {backgroundColor: 'green'},
      hasDecreased && {backgroundColor: 'red'},`  Like what is  `hasIncreased && {backgroundColor: 'green'},
      hasDecreased && {backgroundColor: 'red'},` (this is probably a ternary expression but why did you do && `{backgroundColor: 'red'}`

Comment: It's indeed a ternary expression. What we want to do there is, if `hasIncreased` is true, return the styling containing the green background. If `hasDecreased` is true, we want to return the styling containing the red background.
I like using ternaries for that, since it's concise and to me still very much readable.
Since the `style` property takes an array of styles as well, this seems the easiest way to me at least.

Comment: Thanks champ, even I am great fan of ternary expression but I always though that we need to provide them else condition something like this   `this.state.increased ? {backgroundColor: "green"} : {backgroundColor: "white"}, `  I mean this part  : `{backgroundColor: "white"},`

Comment: True. Usually if you were to use a short-handed if like that, you'd use `condition ? if : else`.
I think I labeled it wrongly as ternary expression, rather it's just making use of operators.
When writing `value && value2`, if the first value is true, it returns the second, otherwise it returns the first.
Basically I'm using the `&&` operator (could use `||` for the inverse) to have an even shorter if-statement.
If it seems a little foreign, feel free to just define a class-method that returns whatever you need with a full-fledged `if`-statement!

Answer (score 0):

Pass modalHeight dynamically from parent component as props

modalView is default style

```
<View style={[styles.modalView, { height: `${modalHeight}` }]}>
```